# Swift UI: code needed for iOS crashes MacOS build

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am coding an app for both iOS and MacOS using SwiftUI.

This code is needed for my radio player to work in background mode in iOS

```
 private func checkSession() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately when I try to build for MacOS I get these errors:

AVAudioSession' is unavailable in macOS
'setActive' is unavailable in Swift
sharedInstance()' is unavailable in macOS

What is the best way to keep the code I need for the iOS build but also get working code in MacOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to conditionally comment out code:

```
#if os(macOS)

#endif
```

or

```
#if os(iOS)

#endif
```

You can also split up your code into files that are only available to your iOS or macOS targets in Xcode.

This can be especially useful with extensions. For example, you could have something like this:

```
extension MyAudioManager {
  func setup() {
    //do iOS setup
  }
}
```

and an equivalent version for macOS.  Then, you could call `.setup()` from a shared file and the method will still be available on either platform.

That strategy using conditional compilation might look something like this:

```
extension MyAudioManager {
#if os(iOS)
  func setup() {
    //do iOS setup
  }
}
#endif
#if os(macOS)
  func setup() {
    //do macOS setup
  }
}
#endif
```